# Pure JS Autocomplete search filter to show best relevant items

Tags: javascript, regex, autocomplete

We have list of data + query string, we need to modify an autocomplete filter logic to show post spots first and then other string which could be streets.

```
// external sorted data usually by name
var data = [
    '45 Some street, bla bla',
    'Again 45 street some',
    'More some street xyz',
    'Guess what? Some street',
    'Post spot №345',
    'Post spot №45',
    'Post spot №66745' 
];

// user input
var query = '45';

// here goes some filter magic

/* RESULT must be

1. Post spot №45 // here "45" appears the closest to "№"
2. Post spot №345 // next closest "45" to "№"
3. Post spot №66745 // last closest "45" to "№"
4. 45 Some street, bla bla // here "45" is start of the string BUT it does not come with "№" on the left, but it the heaviest from other data with no "№" on the left
5. Again 45 street some // next heavy item with "45"
--------
in 4 and 5 could be whatever string, not just "45", search logic must sort it with the closest substring to the start of the query string
*/
```

So as summary it must work like this:

1. If query is number then search for "№" on the left -> if found make it heavy and sort from similar items (all of such items must be at the top of the result list)
2. If query is number or string (not matter) then just sort it with substring position leaders (all of these items comes after items #1)

I broke my brain how to make it as short as possible, help me please!

Or if you know cool and nice pure JS autocomplete with builtin search hook (but the logic is still needed) please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try out the following code snippet to understand how to filter and sort data based on specific criteria. This code is designed to help you learn about filtering and sorting arrays in JavaScript. Use the "Run Code Snippet" button from stackoverflow at the end. Let's dive in!

```js
    // External sorted data usually by name
    var data = [
      '45 Some street, bla bla',
      'Again 45 street some',
      'More some street xyz',
      'Guess what? Some street',
      'Post spot №345',
      'Post spot №45',
      'Post spot №66745'
    ];

    // User input
    var query = '45';

    // Filter function
    function filterData() {
      var filteredData = [];
      var containsNumberSign = [];
      var doesNotContainNumberSign = [];

      // Separate items that contain "№" from those that don't
      data.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.includes(query)) {
          if (item.includes('№')) {
            containsNumberSign.push(item);  // Add item to the array that contains "№"
          } else {
            doesNotContainNumberSign.push(item);  // Add item to the array that doesn't contain "№"
          }
        }
      });

      // Sort the arrays by name
      containsNumberSign.sort();
      doesNotContainNumberSign.sort();

      // Combine the sorted arrays
      filteredData = containsNumberSign.concat(doesNotContainNumberSign);

      // Get the result element
      var resultElement = document.getElementById("result");

      // Clear previous result
      resultElement.innerHTML = "";

      // Display the filtered data
      filteredData.forEach(function(item) {
        var itemElement = document.createElement("p");
        itemElement.textContent = item;
        resultElement.appendChild(itemElement);
      });
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="filterData()">Show Filtered Data</button>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Good luck on your learning journey!

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the exact thing I need. I understand how to sort strings, I need not a sort by name but sort on the closest substring position to the start of the string they must be at the top and alphabetical sort will not do the thing. Also the main point is to make it as minimalistic as possible. Perhaps some RegExp will resolve it. Challenge.